# Moment of Inertia of a rotated quarter circle

Tags: circles, moment-problem

[image: Here's the figure.]

I'm trying to find the moment of inertia of just the quarter circle part for the x1, x2 axis, which I believe would be (being $\rho$ the density):
$$\frac{\rho}{16}\pi+\frac{\pi\rho}{4}(1-\frac{4}{3\pi})^2$$

However I am told that it is instead
$$\frac{\rho}{16}\pi+\frac{\pi\rho}{4}(-(\frac{4}{3\pi})^2+(1-\frac{4}{3\pi})^2)$$

My question is where does the extra $-(\frac{4}{3\pi})^2$ come from? Does it have to do with the quarter circle being rotated in comparison to the ones shown in tabled values? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would you mind posting a picture, just to make sure we get the information right. It almost look like there is an axis offset between your calculation and the solution.

Comment: @Andrei, I have a picture right at the beginning. If you're asking about what tabled values I'm looking at they're the same as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_second_moments_of_area

Comment: There is no link for the figure

Comment: @Andrei That's odd, it shows just fine for me. It's https://i.imgur.com/sN7vjMz.jpg